# Google Apps Script with Immediate Time-Driven Trigger

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, triggers

I'm attempting to test a script that I'm working on.  The script is fine, it executes successfully when I trigger it manually.  I'm just doing a "sanity check" on a time-driven trigger and it's definitely pushing the bounds of my sanity.  I've set it up for a one-time "Specific time / date" execution to test that it will run after I leave it to execute on it's own a la cron or similar.

My problem is that it never executes, I'm setting it up for 2, 3, or 5 minutes after the time when I save it.  Is this not enough time for it to make it's way into Google's cron queue?  Because I can't get this script to execute on a time-driven trigger.

Also, for what it's worth, all Google Apps (Spreadsheet / Docs / etc) calls are being done via the `.getSheetByID()` method so it's not related to the `.getActiveSheet()` problem that can happen when you execute a script with the working document already open in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a poor answer, but I did find that I was able to simply set a time-driven trigger with "every minute" execution, which was enough to finish my work, though I can imagine scenarios where you would want a single trigger as the interface seems to promise, but for me it wouldn't work with soon-scheduled events.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code in your question to look at or comment
However, I use time-driven trigger without any problem - to execute in 2 minutes or more.
with a simple code like below

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger(fname).timeBased().after(afterminutes * 60 * 1000).create();
```

If you still have a problem, please share some code for comments

Comment: I was using the Google Scripts web app UI to setup a trigger, doing so in the script directly doesn't apply to my use case, which is also the reason that I didn't post code.  I'll keep this snippet in mind, however, for future work where it would be applicable.